# How to set html lang attribute in Django template?

Tags: python, django, localization

I wrote a Django application that serves translated content for German users, and English content for everyone else. Currently I use a base template containing:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Obviously this sets the wrong `lang` in case the content is served as German.

Possibly I could try something like

```
<html lang="{{ 'de' if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de' else 'en' }}">
```

but this feels clumsy and hard to maintain in case more languages are added.

What would be a simple way to set `<html lang>` to the actual language served?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The [get_current_language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language) tag contains the preferred language of the user.

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
```

To me the documentation did not make it clear immediately that "preferred language" is not the topmost language from the "Accept-Language" HTTP header but always the language from `setting.LANGUAGES` that best matches the user's preference.

In my case `settings.py` contains:

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
LANGUAGES = [("de", _("German")), ("en", _("English"))]
```

If the user however prefers for example Italien, `get_current_language` will still be `en`. With the Django application running locally on port 8000, you can try this with for example:

```sh
curl -H 'Accept-Language: it' http://127.0.0.1:8000/ | cut -b 1-50
```

The output is something like:

```
<html lang="en">...
```

If no preferred language is provided with the request, the result is the same. So there is no need for a `|default:'en'`. You can test this with:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/ | cut -b 1-50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<html lang="{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE|default:'en' %}">
```

this will add `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` if it available or it will set default value as **en**